# How to determine build type in kotlin-multiplatform project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I’m working on a multiplaform project, iOS and JVM (I’m not targeting Android directly). Depending on the build type (debug or release) I want to configure the logging level (i.e. to print only errors in release). Since there is no a `BuildConfig` class available, how can I know from `commonMain` the build type?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `BuildConfig` in iOS anyway. My guess is that you would need to rig up build type-specific classes that code-generate something that you can use to determine the build type, akin to how the Android build tools code-generate `BuildConfig`. I don't know if there is something in the standard Kotlin Multiplatform build setup that does this automatically.

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 24):

Not a direct answer to the question, but for android/ios one can define a property like this:

in commonMain:

```
expect val isDebug: Boolean
```

in androidMain:

```
import com.yourPackage.BuildConfig

actual val isDebug = BuildConfig.DEBUG
```

in iosMain:

```
import kotlin.native.Platform

actual val isDebug = Platform.isDebugBinary
```

*Note: for Android BuildConfig, you may need to add this in your app's Build.Config*

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What about Js and JVM targets?

Comment: @YektaDev did you found out anything about JVM and JS ?

Comment: @MustafaOzhan I don't clearly remember, but I don't think so.

Comment: But how can you access BuildConfig in androidMain? Isn't it only available in androidApp?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible right now for all possible targets. Build type is resolved only for android.

But you can create two versions of the module e.g. `module` and `module-debug`.

Then declare in `module`:

```kotlin
const val IS_DEBUG = false
```

in `module-debug`:

```kotlin
const val IS_DEBUG = true
```

Finally in the resulting application or module gradle configuration you can declare dependency on what you need. E.g.:

```kotlin
if (DEBUG_ENV)  // you need to set DEBUG_ENV from property or environment variable
    implementation(project(":module-debug"))
else
    implementation(project(":module"))
```

or for android:

```kotlin
debugImplementation(project(":module-debug"))
releaseImplementation(project(":module"))
```

This way you can change logic using `IS_DEBUG` constant for every target or can create even completely different implementations of something in debug and release modules.