# How do I write preprocessor (#if) code in the kotlin iOS part of a multiplatform project?

Tags: swift, kotlin-multiplatform

Straight from [the Kotlin Multiplatform for iOS and Android](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-create-first-app.html#run-your-application-on-ios) tutorial I have a template source file for iOS code which looks like this:

```
class IOSPlatform: Platform {
    override val name: String = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}

actual fun getPlatform(): Platform = IOSPlatform()
```

Now I would like to change the value of the `name` override using iOS `#if/#else/#endif` code mechanism. In typical kotlin fashion I would write something like this for the android platform:

```
class IOSPlatform : Platform {
    override val name: String
        get() {
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                return UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " debug " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
            } else {
                return UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " release " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
            }
        }
}
```

However, there is no `BuildConfig` equivalent for iOS, and obviously I can't write `#if DEBUG` in Kotlin like I would in Swift. Is my only option to call a custom Swift implementation where the `#if` conditional is implemented in a `.swift` source file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine build type in kotlin-multiplatform project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255368/how-to-determine-build-type-in-kotlin-multiplatform-project)

Comment: @PhilDukhov the example is the same because it's the easiest minimal code, but I guess the answer is it's impossible to write preprocessor code in kotlin.

Comment: well yes, there's no such thing in kotlin. I guess `Platform.isDebugBinary` is using it under the hood